# ClamAV - getcvd: Verification: Can't verify database integrity error message when running freshclam

Tags: linux, software-updates, database, zorin, clamav

When I was running freshclam using ClamAV on Zorin Linux OS, it gave me the following errors as shown below. I am new to Linux, so I might need some hand-holding on solving this (step-by-step), if possible. I searched other websites with the same question, but it did not resolve my issue. Thank you!

```
mechalinuxzilla@zorin-vb:~$ sudo freshclam

Thu Jul 30 15:06:37 2020 -> ClamAV update process started at Thu Jul 30 15:06:37 2020
Thu Jul 30 15:06:37 2020 -> daily database available for download (remote version: 25889)
Time: 11.1s, ETA: 0.0s [=============================>] 92.69MiB/92.69MiB       
Thu Jul 30 15:06:48 2020 -> !getcvd: Verification: Can't verify database integrity
Thu Jul 30 15:06:48 2020 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
Thu Jul 30 15:06:53 2020 -> daily database available for download (remote version: 25889)
Time: 10.2s, ETA: 0.0s [=============================>] 92.69MiB/92.69MiB       
Thu Jul 30 15:07:03 2020 -> !getcvd: Verification: Can't verify database integrity
Thu Jul 30 15:07:03 2020 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
Thu Jul 30 15:07:08 2020 -> daily database available for download (remote version: 25889)
Time: 12.8s, ETA: 0.0s [=============================>] 92.69MiB/92.69MiB       
Thu Jul 30 15:07:21 2020 -> !getcvd: Verification: Can't verify database integrity
Thu Jul 30 15:07:21 2020 -> Giving up on https://database.clamav.net...
Thu Jul 30 15:07:21 2020 -> !Update failed for database: daily
Thu Jul 30 15:07:21 2020 -> ^fc_update_databases: fc_update_database failed: Invalid or corrupted CVD/CLD database (7)
Thu Jul 30 15:07:21 2020 -> !Database update process failed: Invalid or corrupted CVD/CLD database (7)
Thu Jul 30 15:07:21 2020 -> !Update failed.
```

Comment: Read [this thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/clamav-error-can%27t-verify-database-integrity-868777/) and it *should* get you sorted. It's older and untested by me - but I am pretty sure it's the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, KGIII, I appreciate the link. I tried everything mentioned in the article, but I keep getting the "!getcvd: Verification: Can't verify database integrity" error message.

Answer (score 1):

After doing quite a bit of research on this, it appears downloading the main.cvd and daily.cvd files manually from clamav.net and doing the freshclam did the trick.  I am not getting the error anymore.  Here is what I did:

```
mechalinuxzilla@zorin-vb:~$ sudo wget http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd

2020-07-31 14:01:50--  http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd
Resolving database.clamav.net (database.clamav.net)... 104.16.219.84, 104.16.218.84, 2606:4700::6810:da54, ...
Connecting to database.clamav.net (database.clamav.net)|104.16.219.84|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 117859675 (112M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘main.cvd’

main.cvd              100%[=======================>] 112.40M  10.1MB/s    in 13s     

2020-07-31 14:02:03 (8.73 MB/s) - ‘main.cvd’ saved [117859675/117859675]


mechalinuxzilla@zorin-vb:~$ sudo wget http://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd

2020-07-31 14:02:38--  http://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Resolving database.clamav.net (database.clamav.net)... 104.16.218.84, 104.16.219.84, 2606:4700::6810:da54, ...
Connecting to database.clamav.net (database.clamav.net)|104.16.218.84|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 97507181 (93M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘daily.cvd’

daily.cvd             100%[=======================>]  92.99M  9.17MB/s    in 11s     

2020-07-31 14:02:49 (8.47 MB/s) - ‘daily.cvd’ saved [97507181/97507181]

mechalinuxzilla@zorin-vb:~$ sudo freshclam

Fri Jul 31 14:02:55 2020 -> ClamAV update process started at Fri Jul 31 14:02:55 2020
Fri Jul 31 14:02:55 2020 -> daily.cvd database is up to date (version: 25890, sigs: 3729086, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
Fri Jul 31 14:02:55 2020 -> main.cvd database is up to date (version: 59, sigs: 4564902, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Fri Jul 31 14:02:55 2020 -> bytecode database available for download (remote version: 331)
Time: 0.1s, ETA: 0.0s [=============================>] 289.44KiB/289.44KiB     
Fri Jul 31 14:02:55 2020 -> Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.a3a04/clamav-7bed49e12b32dadbc775f183c02205c5.tmp-bytecode.cvd' ...
Fri Jul 31 14:02:55 2020 -> Database test passed.
Fri Jul 31 14:02:55 2020 -> bytecode.cvd updated (version: 331, sigs: 94, f-level: 63, builder: anvilleg)
```